# How to handle JMeter Master slave issue

Tags: jmeter

I am using below shell script to execute JMeter from master machine and post execution of Jmeter i am triggering JMeterPluginsCMD.sh to generate jtl to csv file

```
for filepath in /tmp/scripts/*.jmx; do
  filename=$(echo "$filepath" | sed -r "s/.+\/(.+)\..+/\1/")
  echo "Running testplan ${filepath}"
  resultpath="/tmp/results/testresult.jtl"
  logpath="/tmp/results/log/testlog.log"
  jmeter -n -t "$filepath" -l "$resultpath" -R"$SLAVE_IP_ADDRESSES" -
```

Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -j "$logpath"
done

sleep 600
JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv "/tmp/results/test.csv" --input-jtl
"/tmp/results/testresult.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
sleep 600

Above code works fine with limited user load, but under high load when master does not receive below acknowledgment from slave.
021-05-18 06:37:02,457 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Finished remote host: 10.1.1.1

It does not trigger JMeterPluginsCMD.sh.
What are the possible reasons of not receiving this acknowledgment. Is there any way to by pass the communication issue(JMeter Master->slave) and execute
JMeterPluginsCMD.sh with out any fail

Answer (score 0):

If you "by pass the communication issue(JMeter Master->slave)" you won't get any results therefore it will be no sense in running your "JMeterPluginsCMD.sh".

So I would rather suggest

- looking into the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on the slave machine and perhaps on the master machine as well, there is a chance you will be able to figure out what's wrong from the log
- ensure that both have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. see [20 Command Line Tools to Monitor Linux Performance](https://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/) or just go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
- make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

If your current slave machine is not powerful enough in order to conduct the "high load" you might need to add another slave and divide your "high load" by half.